# Is it possible to deploy a Mac based Angular project to Windows Server's IIS?

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, server

I am developing an application on my MacBook Pro in Angular. Is it possible to deploy it to an IIS web server? (exactly: Windows Server 2019)
If yes: are there any differences between how to deploy an Angular app from a Mac to Windows Server 2019's IIS compare to deploy an Angular app from Windows 10 to IIS?

Comment: If you are looking for tutorials, then please use a search engine. Such questions are off topic on Stack Overflow. The official Angular site has something for you to get started, https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: How did you write the angular project? If you use visual studio, you can right click the project and publish to folder. Then copy the folder to server and deploy to IIS.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Vs code and visaul studio are different product. It is better to use visual studio. It can one-click publish project.